# One or more Filters failed to start after adding filters to web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Sorry if this is something trivial, but I'm pretty new to this.

Here's my pom dependencies:

This all works like this, but if I uncomment the `<filter>` part in web.xml I get the

> One or more Filters failed to start.

error. I tried googling it, but without success. I'm using Tomcat 8. I have no idea what else to say about the problem, since I'm trying to figure it out my self. I was following the tutorial from [this](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-custom-login-form-annotation-example/) link (with XML configurations). I tried different spring and spring security versions, but every time the war 'explodes' it gives out the error above (and the application is, of course, unreachable)

Was something updated that I didn't know about.. or am I missing something else? I'll post the full error stack at the bottom.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVCVezba2</display-name>

    <!--filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping-->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/home**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/store**" access="isAuthenticated" />
        <form-login login-page="/home/index" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="123" authorities="USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

error stack:

```
16-Feb-2016 21:15:34.292 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
16-Feb-2016 21:15:34.458 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
16-Feb-2016 21:15:34.757 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 16 21:15:34 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
16-Feb-2016 21:15:34.870 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
16-Feb-2016 21:15:35.990 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/index || /home/ || /home || /index || /]}" onto public java.lang.String com.nemanjat94.controllers.HomeController.index(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.nemanjat94.models.User)
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.218 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 16 21:15:34 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.327 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 16 21:15:34 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.443 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.502 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2044 ms
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.518 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.519 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
16-Feb-2016 21:15:36.531 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 16 21:15:34 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2016-02-16 09:15:36,567] Artifact SpringMVCVezba2:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: *One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file*

Comment: @wero Thing is, I have no idea where to find that.

Comment: Tomcat is your container. its logs are in tomcat/logs. Look for the latest logfile named `catalina<date>.log` and try find a error stacktrace at the end.

Comment: @wero Ah, alright, I'll try to sort it out from there. Thanks.

Comment: Just for complement: The logs in `/var/logs/tomcat8` don't show all stacktrace. Go to tomcat path to get full logs. The default instalations is in `/usr/share/tomcat8/logs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently, the problem was that `springSecurityFilterChain` couldn't be called, so I just moved the content of `spring-security.xml` to `spring-servlet.xml` and it all works as intended now.

I wanted to seperate them by putting `spring-security.xml` in the `contextConfigLocation` in the `web.xml`, but I couldn't add more than one (`spring-servlet.xml`), but looks like that's not going to work very well.

A big thank you to @wero for the logging tip!

Answer (score 3):

There were no logs at all in my case.
It was happening because of one of my Filter implementing class/method was throwing NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Issue : Your application was not able to read "spring-security.xml" file mentioned in web.xml in "context-param".

RCA : Follow the steps To find why/Which Filter failed to start. (Generic approach)
Step 1 : Start your application in Debug Mode and immediately attach remote debuging from your IDE(Eclipse/Intelija...). 
Step 2 : Apply break point in Filter class which you mentioned in your web.xml file. In my case it was "DelegatingFilterProxy". 
Step 3 : Once application hits the break point than enable "Java Exception BreakPoint --> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeansException".
Step 4 : Now IDE will show you exact location where the exception arises. You can further debug and solve this issue easily.

Solution : Make Sure your application was able to read spring-security.xml file mentioned  in "context-param" will solve this issue.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appContext.xml /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Note : From the logs I didnot get any info.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I found out that one of my filters was throwing an exception in the init method and it was logged in /usr/local/tomcat/logs/localhost.2019-12-07.log instead of the 'usual' log (/usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.out or /usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.2019-12-07.log)